# Deleting many rows from a big table MySql 5.5.46

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

The following statement deletes duplicate rows and keeps the highest id

```
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN contacts t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.email = t2.email;
```

This query references the contacts table twice, therefore, it uses the table alias t1 and t2.

But I have a 6 millions rows table and we need to clean it.

My first approach was create a SP with this lines

```
REPEAT
DELETE t1 FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN contacts t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.email = t2.email
ORDER BY t1.id ASC LIMIT 10000;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
```

The error is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'ORDER BY t1.id ASC LIMIT 10000' at line 17 Time: 0,063s

Help me to do it.

Comment: Deletes have no order and you can't use limit, what exacrly do you try to achieve. runnig through and only chelc 10000 rows

Comment: @nbk Pls see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html **Order of Deletion**

Comment: you should have read the Multiple-Table Syntax section as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `ORDER` and `LIMIT` in a **joined** tables in DELETE

**Multiple-Table Syntax**

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)